# Which is the correct past tense of ‘begleiten’?

Tags: verb, conjugation, past-participle, preterite

I have found *begleiten* (to accompany) conjugated two different ways.

[Verbformen.net](http://verbformen.net/conjugation/?i=begleiten) suggests:

> begleiten, begleitete, begleitet

While [Collins Dictionary (Online)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/conjugation/begleiten) suggests:

> begleiten, beglitt, begleitet

Which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the forms *begleitete*, *begleitet* are [correct](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:begleiten).

There is however the verb [gleiten](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gleiten) (to slide). So one can imagine an ad hoc formation of a transitive verb *begleiten* in analogy to *befahren* or *begehen*, as in

> *Ich begleite das Eis.

The past tense would then be:

> *Ich beglitt das Eis.

This makes me smile and is certainly not standard.

Comment: “Das Eis begleiten". Falls das eine besondere Form für ein Gleiten auf dem Eis sein soll, könntest du mal bitte erläurten, was damit gemeint ist und wie das mit "Auf dem Eis gleiten" in Verbindung steht? Nach meiner Kenntnis gibt es die Form nicht.